# How to get URL using regular expression in java?

Tags: java, url

I have url like http://www.google.com/api/js/example and I want to extract only http:/www.google.com  using regular expression in java, how can I get that??

Comment: If your in Java, you shouldn't need to use regex for hardly anything. I use regex when I'm in Bash and that's it - I've never ever needed regex for anything else.

Answer (score 7):

Just use a `URL`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com/api/js/example");
    System.out.println(url.getProtocol() + "://" + url.getHost());
}
```

Comment: +1 this is of course the much smarter solution. using built-in modules is much better than defining an own regex.

Comment: exactly what i thought of but the time I posted it u already did. +1 though